# Não consigo fazer a comparação entrar no elif

Tags: python

Eu preciso fazer um jogo de par ou impar com o computador, eu tentei fazer a comparação do if para saber se escolhi par ou impar com 'Pp' e 'Ii' so que não estava conseguindo, tentei usar o lower() e também não estava indo. decidi usar um `if 'p' or 'P' in pi:` o mesmo para o impar, acontece que mesmo que eu escolha Impar ele ta entrando no laço do par, o que pode ser ?

```
from random import randint
soma = vitorias = 0
while True:
    comp = randint(1, 10)
    print(comp)
    valor = int(input('Digite um valor : '))
    pi = str(input('Par ou Impar ? [P/I]'))
    if 'p' or 'P' in pi:
        soma = valor + comp
        print(f'{valor} + {comp} = {soma}')
            if soma % 2 == 0:
                print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é par, você venceu')
                vitorias += 1
            else:
                print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é impar, você perdeu')
                break
     elif 'i' or 'I' in pi:
            soma = valor + comp
            print(f'{valor} + {comp} = {soma}')
            if soma % 2 != 0:
                print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é impar, você venceu')
                vitorias += 1
            else:
                print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é par, você perdeu')
                break
    print(f'Você teve {vitorias} vitorias consecutivas')
```

Comment: Espero que dê pra entender a formatação, ainda sou meio novo aq no site

Comment: Com o elif desalinhado do resto desse jeito fica complicado avaliar.

Comment: Amigo a sua indentação tá bem ruim

Comment: assim fica melhor de entender ?
http://prntscr.com/ngz0z4 
eu n entendi a parte do elif desalinhado, ele n teria que ficar na msm linha do if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua indentação está ruim, eu testei seu código e deu erro de indentação, e além disso há alguns bugs, por exemplo, se vc digitar Impar, vai cair no If, o melhor a se fazer é usar uma comparação `if pi == 'p' or pi == 'P'`, eu fiz alguns ajustes em seu código, com leves alterações e um melhor indentamento e funciona perfeitamente, sem bugs. Resumindo, melhore sua indentação, indente apenas após funções como `if`, `else`, `while`, `for` e `def`.

```
from random import randint
soma = vitorias = 0
while True:
   comp = randint(1, 10)
   print(comp)
   valor = int(input('Digite um valor : '))
   pi = str(input('Par ou Impar ? [P/I]'))
   if pi == 'p' or pi == 'P': #No cógigo que você postou o erro começa aqui
       soma = valor + comp
       print(f'{valor} + {comp} = {soma}')
       if soma % 2 == 0:
            print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é par, você venceu')
            vitorias += 1
       else:
            print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é impar, você perdeu')
            break
   elif pi == 'i' or pi == 'I':
       soma = valor + comp
       print(f'{valor} + {comp} = {soma}')
       if (soma % 2):
            print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é impar, você venceu')
            vitorias += 1
       else:
            print(f'A soma dos numeros escolhidos foi {soma}, {soma} é par, você perdeu')
            break
   else:
            print('Escolheu a opção errada tente novamente.')
   print(f'Você teve {vitorias} vitorias consecutivas')
```

Comment: Obrigado, trocar o     if 'p' or 'P' in pi:  por  if pi == 'p' or pi == 'P':   deu certo, mas sabe dizer o motivo de n ter dado certo antes ?

Comment: Hum... Não sei :#, consegui corrigir pensando no que poderia fazer melhor.